# Sitecore Analytics api new method in 9.0 version

Tags: sitecore-api

We recently upgraded our project to Sitecore9 initial release from 7.2. We were re-compiling our code including latest Sitecore.Analytics.dll

We are getting this error

if (Tracker.IsActive)
{
      Tracker.Visitor.ExternalUser = domainUser.ToLower();
}

Method not found: 'Sitecore.Analytics.Data.DataAccess.Visitor Sitecore.Analytics.Tracker.get_Visitor()'.

Can someone help me in resolving this?

Answer (score 2):

It looks like you're trying to identify the contact. The code should be changed as per the [documentation for Sitecore 9.0.x](https://doc.sitecore.com/developers/90/sitecore-experience-platform/en/identifying-contacts.html)

Just an example, but it might look something like this

```
if (Tracker.Enabled && Tracker.Current != null && Tracker.Current.IsActive) { 
    Tracker.Current.Session.IdentifyAs("sitecoreextranet", domainUser.ToLower()); 
}
```